# MediaPlayer having issues with playing only once within the list of images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I'm having a problem with my **MediaPlayer** which I have set to play and pause with one button.

It plays on the first click on any position but after this nothing plays and it shows this in logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-23 11:06:40.330 6482-9285/package.com W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
08-23 11:06:40.330 6482-9285/package.com W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1078)
08-23 11:06:40.330 6482-9285/package.com W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:103
```

I call this method within a getView method in my CustomListAdapter and the sounds are passed in by arrays through TabActivities:

```
public void setTheSounds(ImageView playPause, final int position){
        try {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if(!mp.isPlaying()){
                            mp.setDataSource(sound[+position]);
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                        } else {
                            mp.pause();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("GGGGGG", "prepare() failed");
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088537/4056108)

Answer (score 0):

[Click Hear](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/). I think it will help you to handle media player callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset Media player object before passing new value.

Comment: I had this but the thing is the user can pause and then play another mp3 within the list so wasn;t working correctly: 
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.reset();
            }
        });